# Assembly:CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc Error , Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

ECould not load file or assembly `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: A piece of explanation would be great.. What is the problem? What is your work? etc..

Comment: add error message that batter understand.